# How to overflow-x visible with scrollable container and parent with position relative inside

Tags: css, overflow

Here is an image

[image: 1]

On image you can see two blue squares outside of layout, that must scroll in red block. They are relative to blue line to set their horizontal position. Small blue blocks are inside blue line in markup and have position absolute

If blue line hasn't position relative, then overflow is correct, but i need to scroll overflowed squares with line in red block

Comment: Please do not just show pictures, but present a proper [mre] of your issue. Seeing the actual code, is often much easier to understand (and experiment with, if someone wants to try and come up with a solution that works with your specific code), than having just a verbal description of what you thought were the most important details.

Comment: Depending on the specifics, this might need a solution like outlined in https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/